# Über den Ausdruck "Stand heute"

Tags: phrase

> Medienkompetenz scheint **Stand heute** also auch weiterhin ein Thema zu sein, um das sich Eltern zusammen mit engagierten Lehrkräften und Pädagogen eigenverantwortlich kümmern müssen.

Heute bin ich über den Ausdruck "Stand heute" gestolpert. Da es in einem Artikel erschienen ist, gehe ich davon aus, dass es zur Hochsprache gehört. Laut [Openthesaurus](https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/Stand%20heute) ist er jedoch ein jargonhafter Ausdruck.

Kann ich also den Ausdruck in schriftlichen Texten verwenden oder nur in der gesprochenen Sprache?

Comment: Meiner Beobachtung nach trifft man diesen Ausdruck nur in geschriebenen Texten. Der Grund: Viele Leute wollen, wenn sie etwas schreiben, besonders klug wirken, und machen sich viel mehr Gedanken über die Formulierung. Dabei fällt ihnen dann ein, dass sie Floskeln wie »Stand heute« schon mal wo gelesen (aber selbst nicht so recht verstanden) haben, und weil sie das für gehobene Sprache halten, packen sie es dann in ihre Texte, häufig noch mit vielen Fremdwörtern. Leute, die so schreiben, würden so einen Quatsch nie in gesprochener Sprache absondern.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich weiß nicht, ob sich das in den vergangenen Jahren stark gewandelt hat (vielleicht! Mir selbst fällt der Ausdruck gefühlt erst seit recht kurzer Zeit auf.), aber heute (Stand 2021, um das mal so auszudrücken ;) ) scheint die Formulierung auch im gesprochenen Deutsch völlig gängig zu sein.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Ich gebe dir recht. Das, was ich da vor dreieinhalb Jahren geschrieben habe, würde ich heute nicht mehr behaupten.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Für mein Sprachempfinden ist *Stand heute* Bürokratenjargon. Man tut seinen Lesern einen Gefallen, wenn man solche Ausdrücke vermeidet.

Wenn man *Stand heute* überhaupt verwenden will in schriftlichen Äußerungen, sollte man es aber jedenfalls als Einschub behandeln, also z.B. durch Kommas abtrennen wie im ersten Beispiel in Min-Soo Pipefeets Antwort.

> Es gibt, Stand heute, schon 1,5 Millionen aktive "e-Sportler"

Auch Separierung durch Gedankenstriche oder Klammern würde gehen.

> Es gibt - Stand heute - schon 1,5 Millionen Hobbyjodler.
>
> Es gibt (Stand heute) schon 1,5 Millionen organisierte Klöppelfreunde.

Guter Stil ist es aber so oder so nicht.

Es gibt - Stand heute wie Stand gestern - jede Menge Alternativen. Bei Ihrer Auswahl kommt es natürlich auf den Kontext an. Ist es wichtig, mitzuteilen, dass hier von einer sich täglich ändernden Zahl gesprochen wird (etwa Anmeldungen zu einer Konferenz), oder geht es eher darum, sich abzusichern im Sinne von "so viel man heute weiß", also als Hinweis darauf, dass man sich bewusst ist, dass der Erkenntnisprozess vielleicht noch andauert?

Hinweis auf sich laufend änderende Zahlen:

> Es gibt bereits 1,5 Millionen xyz (Zahlen vom 10.11.2017)
>
> Es gibt heute bereits 1,5 Millionen...
>
> Nach jüngsten Untersuchungen gibt es derzeit...
>
> Der letzte Stand der Anmeldungen (Stichtag 10.11.2017) war...
>
> Zum Stichtag 10.11.2017 gab es...

Distanzierung von der Behauptung durch Verweis auf fortdauernden  Erkenntnisprozess:

> Es gibt nach heutigem Kenntnisstand...
>
> Es gibt nach heutigem Stand des Wissens...
>
> Es gibt nach heutigem Stand...
>
> Es gibt nach heutigem Wissen
>
> Heute glaubt man, dass...

Im Beispiel in der Eingangsfrage

> *Medienkompetenz scheint Stand heute also auch weiterhin ein Thema zu sein

ist "Stand heute" aber in der schlechsten denkbaren Form eingesetzt. Hier geht es ja gar nicht um einen Zählerstand, der sich täglich ändern kann, so dass ein solcher präzisierender Einschub sinnvoll wäre. Vermutlich hat der Autor gemeint:

> Medienkompetenz ist **nach heutiger Kenntnis** also auch weiterhin ein Thema.

Jedoch ist das eigentlich ebenfalls Wortgebimmel. "Nach heutiger Kenntnis" kann man schadlos weglassen, denn nach welcher Kenntnis, wenn nicht der heutigen, sollte man denn sonst beurteilen, was weiterhin ein Thema ist? Den Kenntnisstand von morgen hat man ja noch nicht, und der von gestern ist für eine Aussage zum Heute irrelevant. Man kann somit ohne irgend einen Verlust an Präzision sagen:

> Medienkompetenz ist also weiterhin ein Thema.

Oder, wenn man sich nicht traut, eine solche Behauptung unverblümt im Indikativ aufzustellen, kann man sich etwas zurücknehmen und sagen:

> Medienkompetenz scheint also auch weiterhin ein Thema zu sein.

(Dass dies "Stand heute" - nämlich zur Stunde da der Autor die Worte niederschrieb - so gesehen wird, versteht sich hier von selbst.)

---

Nebenbei: Der Satz

> *Medienkompetenz scheint Stand heute also auch weiterhin ein Thema zu sein.

ist noch aus einem anderen Grund unglücklich formuliert. Fügt man eine Einschränkung wie "Stand heute" oder "nach heutiger Kenntnis" ein, so sind weitere Marker der Distanzierung von der Behauptung ("scheint zu sein") überflüssig da doppeltgemoppelt.

Herrje. Ein einziger Satz und so viel Unfug drin!

Sprachkompetenz und Stilistik sind definitiv auch heute noch Themen, denen man sich widmen sollte.

Comment: "Bürokratenjargon": ja, klingt aber vor allem nach militärischem Statistiker,  oder RTL-BWLer im Controlling. Blähwort?

Answer (score 5):

Meinem Sprachempfinden nach ist der Ausdruck "Stand heute" zwar recht unförmlich, aber dennoch für die Schriftsprache tauglich. Allerdings findet er, glaube ich, erst in den letzten Jahren Eingang in die Schriftsprache.

Meine Recherche bei Google Books scheint dieses Sprachempfinden zu bestätigen. Ich habe mehrere Treffer gefunden, ausschließlich neueren Datums (ab 2000):

- [Es gibt, Stand heute, schon ca. 1,5 Mio. aktive "e-Sportler".](https://books.google.de/books?id=ObLSJ2GuNS0C&pg=PA8&dq=%22stand%20heute%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSwaDp67bXAhWQLewKHdhUAG0Q6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=%22stand%20heute%22&f=false)
- [Ausgenommen von der Neuregelung sind Stand heute Frauen und Schwerbehinderte.](https://books.google.de/books?id=tw_ABgAAQBAJ&pg=PP6&dq=%22stand%20heute%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSwaDp67bXAhWQLewKHdhUAG0Q6AEITTAH#v=onepage&q=%22stand%20heute%22&f=false)
- [Meines Wissens ist Stand heute ein solcher Ansatz noch nicht realisiert, ...](https://books.google.de/books?id=SloiBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA171&dq=%22stand%20heute%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit_Ljz67bXAhXRqKQKHXf5AEQ4ChDoAQg3MAM#v=onepage&q=%22stand%20heute%22&f=false)
- [Kein Sicherheitsexperte kann Stand heute die Risiken der täglich wachsenden, weltweit vernetzten Geräte exakt abschätzen, geschweige denn eindämmen!](https://books.google.de/books?id=SL7ADgAAQBAJ&pg=PA263&dq=%22Stand%20heute%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHn6qv67bXAhVC66QKHSzNAGk4ChDoAQgmMAA#v=onepage&q=%22Stand%20heute%22&f=false)
- [..., dass eine einfache Presswerkzeugoptimierung Stand heute schon möglich ist.](https://books.google.de/books?id=6d32AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA229&dq=%22Stand%20heute%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwiJnL67bXAhWB_qQKHaisAKE4KBDoAQg8MAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Stand%20heute%22&f=false)

Einer der Autoren benutzt den Ausdruck gleich drei(!) Mal in einem Absatz:
["Dieses Buch haben wir im Jahre 2016 geschrieben, Stand heute ist es dank der sich stets weiterentwickelnden Medien leichter denn je, alternative Jobangebote zu finden... "](https://books.google.de/books?id=HTCkDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA31&dq=%22Stand%20heute%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi55--667bXAhWQCOwKHdm7AJc4FBDoAQgmMAA#v=onepage&q=%22Stand%20heute%22&f=false)
Diese extreme Anhäufung fällt bei mir unter *schlechter Stil*.

Answer (score 2):

[DWDS corpora](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=%40Stand%20heute&corpus=zeit&date-start=1946&date-end=2018&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=10), hier beispielsweise aus *Die Zeit*, wimmeln von Treffern für *Stand heute*, wobei der älteste Treffer aus dem Jahr 2003 stammt:

> Wenn wir Stand heute 10 Millionen mehr Menschen im arbeitsfähigen Alter hätten, hätten wir dann 10 Millionen mehr Beitragszahler oder 10 Millionen mehr Beitragsempfänger (Arbeitslosengeld, Sozialhilfe)?

(Nebenbei: Hier könnte man *Stand* ersatzlos streichen.)

Die grammatikalische Behandlung ist aber sehr uneinheitlich, anders als bei *nach heutigem (Kenntnis-)Stand*. Da gibt es außer dem Einschub (mit Gedankenstrichen oder Kommata abgetrennt) auch den Versuch der fugenlosen Verwendung, für die sich auch in den anderen Antworten Beispiele finden:

> "Stand heute werden wir 2010 mit Gewinn abschließen und so mit Rückenwind in das Jahr 2011 starten", sagte Commerzbank-Finanzvorstand Eric Strutz am Donnerstag in Frankfurt.

Ich halte das für grammatikalisch zweifelhaft.